# How to check if auto suggestion exists?

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, webdriver, autosuggest, webdriverwait

I need to check whether the window with search suggestions exists.When you type something in search a list of suggested searches appears. I need to check whether this pop up window exists.

[That window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J9gDi.png)

Code trials:

```
import time
import unittest
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException

class YandexSearchRu(unittest.TestCase):

def setUp(self):
    self.driver = webdriver.Chrome()

def test_search(self):
    driver = self.driver
    driver.get("http://www.yandex.ru")
    try:
        input = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='text']")
    except NoSuchElementException:
        driver.close()
    input.send_keys("Тензор")
    input.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
    time.sleep(5)

def tearDown(self):
    self.driver.close()

if __name__ == "__main__":

unittest.main()
```

Comment: Please fix your code... most of the code is not actually formatted as code. The suggestion window is just HTML. It likely has a top level element that is present if it is present. Check for the visibility of that element.

Comment: Provide the HTML of the page and elements you are trying to select.  Add an appropriate description to your question and check [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

Try to do this:

```
driver.get("http://www.yandex.ru")
try:
    input = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='text']")
    input.send_keys("adfadf")
    popup = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "body > div. i-bem.popup > div.popup__content")))
    if popup.is_displayed():
        print("popup disyplayed")
    else:
        print("popup not visible")
except NoSuchElementException:
```

Answer (score 0):

The element isn't a *pop up window* but *Auto Suggestions* and to extract the *Auto Suggestions* you can use the following solution:

- Code Block:

  ```
  from selenium import webdriver
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

  options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
  options.add_argument('start-maximized')
  options.add_argument('disable-infobars')
  options.add_argument('--disable-extensions')
  driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options, executable_path=r'C:\WebDrivers\chromedriver.exe')
  driver.get('http://www.yandex.ru')
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input.input__control.input__input"))).send_keys("Тензор")
  print([auto_suggestion.text for auto_suggestion in WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.popup__content>div.suggest2__content.suggest2__content_theme_normal li>span.suggest2-item__text")))])
  ```
- Console Output:

  ```
  ['тензор', 'тензор официальный сайт', 'тензор техподдержка', 'тензорное исчисление', 'тензор спб', 'тензорные ядра', 'тензорный анализ', 'тензор эцп', 'тензорезистор', 'тензор инерции']
  ```